# Android Studio logcat history/buffer size

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat

Does anyone know if there a way to increase the size of the logcat history/buffer in Android Studio? I remember there was a way to do it in Eclipse and was hoping Android Studio had a similar setting.

Comment: The currently accepted answer didn't work, but [this new one does](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76309719) now

Answer (score 100, accepted):

You can also do it per project, via the IDE:
Settings->Editor->General->Console: tick "Override console cycle buffer size.  Enter your desired size in the text box.

Finally restart Android Studio for the changes to take effect.

[image]

Comment: @MartinPfeffer - I've added some text description for you.

Comment: It would be nice if you edit the answer to include another point: "Restart Android Studio for the changes to take effect" as indicated by @ElyessAbouda

Answer (score 19):

You can increase the value of `idea.cycle.buffer.size=1024` in property file `android-studio\bin\idea.properties`, buffer size unit: (Kb). I have already try, and it works for me perfect!

Configuration description as following :

```
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# This option controls console cyclic buffer: keeps the console output size not higher than the specified buffer size (Kb).
# Older lines are deleted. In order to disable cycle buffer use idea.cycle.buffer.size=disabled
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
idea.cycle.buffer.size=1024
```

Comment: nm, is documented as Kb in the file...so I assume KiloBytes despite the capitalization.

Answer (score 10):

In Android Electric Eel 2022.1.1 Patch 1 ([with new logcat](https://medium.com/@stevdza-san/new-logcat-in-android-studio-dolphin-is-amazing-cce5ffecb07b)) any of older answers in here didn't worked for me... in settings -> Editor -> General -> Console I don't have "console cyclic buffer" option, instead I have "Console commands history size" which can take at most 1000 (bigger num after pressing Apply will be reduced to 1000) and thats not true, I do have more lines in output.. also setting `idea.cycle.buffer.size` to some high value, `0` or `disabled` didn't make any changes (yes, IDE was restarted few times)

But I've found (new?) section in **Settings -> Tools -> Logcat** and in here we have **"Logcat cycle buffer size"**. Changing this value worked for me (by default it was 1024)

[image: logcat buffer settings in Android Studio 2022]

edit: worth noting that we can also change **on-device buffer size** (in Developer Options). After setting above AS buffer size even hot device plug-in will give more historical logs at beginning

Answer (score 6):

I'm afraid currently it is not possible to change logcat buffer size. However, I've created feature request in AOSP issue tracker. Here's the link: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=73425

Comment: It is possible to increase the size.  The other answers show how.  Your feature request is to make the size unlimited.

Comment: I'm not sure if it was possible at the time of writing my answer (please note the dates), but right now it can be done easily.

Comment: @themichaelscott you can make it unlimited by setting `idea.cycle.buffer.size=disabled`.

Answer (score 2):

Note that idea.cycle.buffer.size is documented in http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/configuration with the following :

```
#----------------------------------------------------------------
# This option controls console cyclic buffer: keeps the console output size not higher than the specified buffer size (Kb).
# Older lines are deleted. In order to disable cycle buffer use idea.cycle.buffer.size=disabled
#----------------------------------------------------------------
idea.cycle.buffer.size=1024
```

Comment: Thank you for including the reference to documentation!

Comment: New doc URL is [https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config.html](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config.html)

Comment: Setting the value to `disabled` seems to make it unlimited.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively mainly when you have big size of data and you wanna temporarily review it, use filter (package Logcat priority) and store output output to a file.