# Increase Debug (logcat?) size in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, debugging, logcat

I have this `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException` problem and I want to trace it in my code, but Android Studio is not giving me enough Back Stack (Debug and Logcat tabs) to see where the problem starts. I want to increase the size of the shown debug info, but I don't know how to do it.

I already tried the two methods shown here : [Android Studio logcat history/buffer size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24685302/android-studio-logcat-history-buffer-size) but they don't seem to work, I am always getting the same debug info.

```
 --------- beginning of crash
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.zboot.alarm1, PID: 3011
                  java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 7, size is 7
                      at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
                      at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
                      at com.bignerdranch.expandablerecyclerview.Adapter.ExpandableRecyclerAdapter.getItemViewType(ExpandableRecyclerAdapter.java:233)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5631)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5563)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5559)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2229)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1556)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1516)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:608)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3693)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:3109)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                      at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.internalMeasureChildren(ConstraintLayout.java:934)
                      at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:973)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                      at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:714)
                      at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:786)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                      at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2643)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2100)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1216)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1452)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
                      at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
                      at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
                      at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
                      at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                    at j
```

Comment: It is working, you just have to restart Android Studio after changing the buffer size to take effect

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio logcat history/buffer size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24685302/android-studio-logcat-history-buffer-size)

Comment: @itabdullah if you read the whole question, you won't flag this is as a possible duplicate

Answer (score 0):

Not the exact solution that you are asking for but rather one of the best ways to get the exception trace.

You should log all the exceptions over Crashlytics using:

```
Crashlytics.logException(e);
```

All the logged exceptions will be reported as Non-Fatal errors.